# Cassandra: concurrent queries for each partition or allow filtering

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Say I have the following Cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE experiment(
    bin text,
    x double,
    y double,
    PRIMARY KEY ((bin), x)
);
```

And I want to get the y values where x is greater than 10. Which one of the following two approaches would be the most efficient?

1. Enabling allow filtering:

   ```
   SELECT x, y FROM experiment WHERE x > 10 ALLOW FILTERING;
   ```
2. Omitting the need for allow filtering by first getting the list of partition keys and subsequently running multiple concurrent queries, one per partition.

   ```
   SELECT distinct bin FROM experiment;
   SELECT x, y FROM experiment WHERE bin = <bin> AND x > 10; //for each bin
   ```

Is there an alternative approach possible (with altered table design perhaps) that is more efficient?

Thanks in advance!

**edit as an answer to a comment**:

This is a constructed example. The real data will be a list of various sensor measurements:

```
time-stamp, subject-id, temperature, noise ...
```

The query we want to make is give me noise levels (over all measurements, on all subjects) where temperature is below 10 degrees. I don't mind switching to a different table design with a different partition strategy if that would benefit the query.

Comment: Can you list all queries that you would perform with this table? That will help us understand why "bin" was chosen as partition key in first place.

Comment: I added a response by editing the original question.